# C++ __attribute__ aligned meaning

Tags: c++, attributes, alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GCC __attribute__((aligned(x)) explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841433/gcc-attribute-alignedx-explanation)
>   [What is meaning of the ‘_attribute_((aligned(4)));’ in the first line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055495/what-is-meaning-of-the-attribute-aligned4-in-the-first-line)

What does these two pieces of code mean? In particular, the `__attribute__ ((aligned(..)))` parts.

```
struct my_struct {
  int64_t a;
  int64_t b;
} __attribute__ ((aligned(16)));
```

and

```
struct my_struct2 { double arr[4] __attribute__((aligned(64))); };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CPU registers often point to memory.

When you increment a register, it points 64 bits further on a 64 bit machine.
However, if you want to get to a byte inside that section, the compiler has to do more work.

If you **align** memory on the "edges" of memory, the registers can access them much faster.  It also means structure members are padded so some space is wasted.  If you do a memory dump of the structure, you may be surprised at the padding.

Comment: In macOS the compiler align any array to 16 Byte. Does GCC do that as well on 64 Bit system?

Comment: 1) I have no idea. 2) If you have a new question, you should start a new question and not tag on.   3)  Necro posting (posting to very old threads) is frowned upon.